# How to find a relative element based on another one by using Appium[Android]?

Tags: android, ui-automation, appium

I try to use Appium to get one *Wifi Adapter(Let's call it *AP*)*'s status(such like *'Saved, Secured'*) in the *system Wi-Fi UI(Android Platform)*, but they are different elements.
Is there a way we can find the element(*'Saved, Secured'*) based on another one(*AP*)? I know they are the children elements of one RelativeLayout element which is the container.

Sorry I don't have enough points to post an image, or it will give you guys a clearer description.
If you guys think the question is useful, please vote it, then I can get some basic points.
  :-)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood your problem, you should drop an eye on the xpath function.
(here is a tutorial to use it well http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.fr/2013/06/xpath-tutorials-identifying-xpath-for.html)

And with it and the function named source, you should be able to do want you want.

(those function are named this way in ruby, I don't know for other languages)

Comment: Thanks for your post, xPath is a good solution for finding sibling elements.

Comment: I use the Appium Python Client, so just post my python code here:       `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='AP']/../android.widget.TextView[@text='Saved, Secured']")`

Answer (score 0):

You could do below as well to find child elements.this is c# sample

```
IWebelememt parent = driver.findelement(selector);
IWebelement child = parent.findlement(Selector);
```

Comment: siblings are not parent/child relationship, they are in the same level